# Hard drive problem (slow reads and writes) Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, io

Recently I built a new box with i7 cpu 6Gb of ram and SAMSUNG Spinpoint F3 HD103SJ 1TB 7200 RPM 32MB Cache SATA 3.0Gb/s 3.5"

The new box is running Ubuntu 10.04

I noticed that this powerful machine I built runs slower than my 3yrs old box when it comes to IO intensive tasks. For example when I run simpletest (testing framework) on my codebase it takes 3-5 more time on the new box..

Is there a way I can try to pin point this problem and make sure that hardive is a problem (or not).

I did run bonnie++ test on both boxes:

Old - http://pastebin.com/VDuv2EjB
New box - http://pastebin.com/Laq8tGAd

When I was comparing 2 reports I spotted big difference in Sequential IO Per Chr section.

What can cause such a difference and is it the indicator of the potential problem?

I hope to hear some suggestion and recommendations for further debugging..

Comment: If this is a workstation this should be moved to superuser. If this is a server, what is the architecture of the old box? Are you using the same filesystems on both?

Comment: Hi. Yes, it's a workstation. Should I just copy paste the question to poveruser, or there is a way to move it. Old box is on ext3 (Ubuntu 7.10 32bit) and new one is xfs (Ubuntu 10.04 64bit).

Comment: What kernel-version do you have? (run `uname -r`)? Have you updated/upgraded it all?

Answer (score 0):

check S.M.A.R.T. data- run Hard Drive Utility:

`palimpsest`

this is form “gnome-disk-utility” package, it is a GUI and see under SMART info

Also check in BIOS if this SATA port is part of some RAID configuration and disable it

can move the disk to different SATA channel with different cable even on different motherboard